# segmentation fault (core dumped) in realloc()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc, coredump

why does the following program give a Segmentation fault error ??
(*This code has more of an educational aspect.*)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void increase_(char ***pptr) 
{    
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        *pptr = (char **)realloc(*pptr, i * sizeof(char *));
        *pptr[i-1] = (char *)malloc(i * sizeof(char));
        *pptr[i-1][0] = i;                
    }            
}

int main() 
{
    char **ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    increase_(&ptr);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        printf("%d\n", ptr[i][0]);
    return(0);
}
```

output of program:

```
1
2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `*pptr[i-1]` exhibits undefined behavior for `i > 1`, as `pptr` points to an "array" of size 1 (namely, a singular varialbe `ptr`). You might have meant `(*pptr)[i-1]`. Or you could just write `ptr[i-1]` - it's unclear why you use an extra level of indirection.

Comment: once you fixed it you may call yourself a [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) :P

Comment: Since the question is tagged with `c++`, you should consider using a `std::vector` rather than `malloc` and `realloc` the memory yourself to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're asking about their differences.

Comment: Why do 100 `realloc`s with increasing size instead of allocating all you need at once?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks , I used (*pptr)[] and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation faults are due to a invalid dereferencing of a pointer. I ran this program at Online C Compiler, and immediately there was a segmentation fault, without your `1` or `2` in the output. According to the Online C Compiler the segmentation fault happened in the `increase_()` function. Try to limit the level of dereference that your pointer has. My C book said that only up to two levels in practical, and beyond that it is very cumbersome to deal with.